# Can an iOS app add podcasts to the iPod library on the device?

Tags: ios, ipod, podcast

I would like to create an application that accesses and downloads podcasts specific to the app.  At the same time, the new podcasts that the app downloads, I would like to add to the iPod music library on the device.  Does anyone know if this is possible?

I haven't seen any apps that can download content (not just podcast) and add it to the iPod library of the iOS device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I haven't seen any apps that can download content (not just podcast) and add it to the iPod library of the iOS device.

That's because it's not possible.

Comment: hello,   Yes that is not possible to add the content to iPod library. but is it possible to download the content into your app only and then play it from your app itself?

Comment: @HiveHicks can you please tell me the way you get the podcast episode details?

Comment: @Darshan as with any other media entity in iPod library - using `MPMediaEntity`'s `valueForProperty:` method http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMediaEntity_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MPMediaEntity/valueForProperty:

Answer (score 0):

Update: this is now possible for jailbroken devices. With my library, [libipodimport](http://github.com/H2CO3/libipodimport), you can add songs to the iPod library.

Comment: Any guidance on how to do this without requiring the MobileSubstrate?  I'd like to be able to do it on non-jailbreak devices, even though it wouldn't be able to go into the App Store.

Comment: @WayneHartman You can't, basically, as far as I'm concerned (there have been attempts to do it). Only SpringBoard and the iTunesStore app has the necessary privileges to do this.

Comment: No way to hook SpringBoard without the substrate?

Comment: The Apple Podcast app that you can download from the AppStore can add podcasts to the library, so I'm thinking there might be some private API that allows it from any app.